# Convert web app into mobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a web application which I built using jQuery mobile it's actually suppose to be a mobile application but it all in HTML, CSS, PHP and javascript. It works good in a browser and I can load it up from my wamp server but it originally suppose to be a phone app how can I turn that into a phone app? I have tried sencha, and my xdk does not even loaded. I dont want to end up in re-coding the entire app. I want to use my existing .html file and .css and and .js and I understand that there are some basic event handlers that will be different from event handler on a web browser. Any help is appreaciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that you want to turn this into a native mobile app? In other words, something you would download from the app store or Google's marketplace.

Comment: @Carter yes that exactly what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)? You'll still end up having to re-write some of your code to fit in with the framework, but it will run natively.